# Creating Merged Html report with Ncover

Tags: c#, ncover

I am able to  create the merged xml reports of several xml files using ncover.reporting.exe but I want the consolidated report in html format having all those graphs and coverage summary.

Please suggest how to modify the below statement to get the html report after merging

ncover.reporting.exe coverage1.xml files\coverage2.xml //s mergedcoverage.xml

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool which you could execute from nant:

[http://www.kiwidude.com/blog/2006/10/ncoverexplorer-merging-ncover-reports.html](http://kiwidudeuk.blogspot.in/2006/10/ncoverexplorer-merging-ncover-reports.html)

Comment: I dont want nant task. need to exceute directly from commandline.